# Cancelling Javascript Interval Alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an alert which fires every 10 milliseconds and checks a PHP file for a variable. If this variable is present the alert fires, however when closing the alert is appears 10 millisecond again, and again and again ... I have found the following code to try and cancel the Interval but it's not working, can anyone help/

Here is the alert script:

```
<script>
        var timerID = 0;
            var callme=function () {
                  $('#alertDiv').load('checkLive.php');
                };
            $(function(){


            timerID = setInterval(callme,1000);});
</script>
```

And here is the cancel js:

```
<script>
        $('#alertDiv').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {

          $('timerID').blur(function () {
            clearInterval(timerID);
          });
        });
</script>
```

I'm a bit of a novice to code and have no idea what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Are the two snippets in the same window object?

Comment: @cDima The scripts sit at the bottom of the page before the body closes. Each within their own script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh,

When using events, these ones bubble - well, gets from the node to the Document element. This means that you can't listen for an event on an element that isn't a parent.
Let's take this as example:

```
<div class="parent-element-1">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent-element-2">
    <div class="element-2"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, if the element-2 triggers an event, the event will bubble from element-2 to parent-element-2. However, parent-element-1 and element-1 will not be aware of it.

This said, you need to listen on this element from another parent.
To be sure that the event is fired:

```
$(document).on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
    clearInterval(timerID);
});
```

However, I would suggest to make an AJAX request using the jQuery API in your case, which allows you to handle much better success/errors, etc. `.load()` is fine when you want to load something from the provided URL and to put it in the calling element. Otherwise, `.ajax()` is way better.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly, when your custom event `closed.bs.alert` is triggered, then you want to cancel your timer. It seems your `blur` event handler is extraneous.

Your cancel event should be:

```
$('#alertDiv').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
    clearInterval(timerID);
});
```

Comment: Cheers for this tip! Have removed the blur but the alert still fires!

Comment: Well, are you sure the `closed.bs.alert` event is even fired? Put a `debugger;` or `alert()` in there to make sure the event is being triggered.

Comment: hmm doesn't seem the `closed.bs.alert` event isn't being fired... hmmm